# cannot find AudioTrack.write(float[], int, int, int) in Android

Tags: android, audiotrack

Reading the AudioTrack official documentation, I noticed I can write an array of float then read it in a streaming or a buffer mode:

> public int write (float[] audioData, int offsetInFloats, int sizeInFloats, int writeMode)
>   Added in API level 21
>
> Writes the audio data to the audio sink for playback (streaming mode),
>   or copies audio data for later playback (static buffer mode). In
>   static buffer mode, copies the data to the buffer starting at offset
>   0, and the write mode is ignored. In streaming mode, the blocking
>   behavior will depend on the write mode.

I tried using it in my code like this:

```
        ....

        float[]raw2=bytesToFloats(read(f2));
        int convhandle= FFTProcessor.createFastConvolutionContext(raw1.length, raw1, im1);
        long t1=System.currentTimeMillis();
        FFTProcessor.performFastConvolution(convhandle, raw2, im2);
        long t2=System.currentTimeMillis()-t1;
        int minSize=audio.getMinBufferSize(22050, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT);
        audio = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,22050, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_8BIT, minSize ,AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        audio.write(raw2, 0, raw2.length, WRITE_NON_BLOCKING);
        audio.play();
        ......
```

But I get this error at the write() method:

```
The method write(byte[], int, int) in the type AudioTrack is not applicable for the arguments (float[], int, int, int)
```

I updated my sdk, and checked the manifest file, `android:targetSdkVersion="21" />`
 but still dont know what's wrong.

Comment: What is your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: @StenSoft <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

Comment: You cannot use functions that are not available in your `minSdkVersion` unless you decorate the class/method with `@TargetApi`. Note that using that call on lower API will crash your application.

Comment: so i can't use it :(

Comment: are you using eclipse ?

Comment: You can use it but only on API that supports it. You can check the API level that the application is running on with `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and fallback to some other method or not offer that functionality on lower APIs.

Comment: my API level is 19.. how can i tell if it supports it or not?

Answer (score 0):

replace this;

```
float[]raw2=bytesToFloats(read(f2));
```

with this;

```
byte[]raw2=read(f2);
```

and replace this;

```
FFTProcessor.performFastConvolution(convhandle, raw2, im2);
```

with this;

```
FFTProcessor.performFastConvolution(convhandle, bytesToFloats(raw2), im2);
```

Comment: that does not perform the convolution.

Comment: ok, but i think your message suggests you are trying to pass float[] into the method instead of byte[]